# get total number of radio button in radio group android

Tags: android, radio-button

I have a dynamic set of radio button in a radio group and I want the total number of button present in it. In this particular case, I have two radio button but how can I get the count of two?

```
                    for (int i = 0; i < listArray.length; i++) {
                       
                        rb = new RadioButton(this);
                        rb.setId(i);
                        rb.setTextColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                        rb.setText(i);
                      

                        rg.addView(rb, layoutParams);
                    }
```

Comment: `radioGroup.getChildCount()`  , did you try this?

Answer (score 2):

You could use
`rg.getChildCount();`